# Please critique E-R diagram of datamodel

Tags: database-design, relational-database, erd

I'm building the data model for the website of a student club at my university and I need some feedback on what I have so far.

Every term students become members by paying a membership fee. This membership fee entitles them to attend all the club's activities less social events during that term. To attend these social events they are required to purchase a ticket.

The club's activities involved courses of 8 to 10 weekly classes, workshops, and the aforementioned events.

We would like to be able to model members every term and track registration and attendance to courses ( just registration ), individual classes ( attendance ), workshops ( attendance and registration), and events (attendance and registration).

We want to be able to see what member of the executive was involved in which activity.

We want the executive to be able to upload articles (text), pictures, music, and video and control who has access to these items. I used a group solution because I think granting access at user/piece of content level is too tedious.

Please take a look and give me some feedback. I'm trying to design a model that is easy to maintain and adapt to new requirements and that is robust, and flexible when it comes to modelling club and member activity.

The password hash will be a part of the student entity. It's currently not showing on the digram.

You can find the diagram below.

EDIT1:

Added legend.

At the top, the rectangle around the Student--Membership--Term is called an aggregation. This means that when used in relationship Registration, for example, we can look at this aggregation as an entity with primary key (student_id, term).

EDIT2: The triangle with the ISA label on it denotes specialization of the top entity into child entities. When translating into a schema we can choose to create a relation for each, or just the children.

Comment: It would be nice to have a legend for the diagram because it's not really a common notation you're using. What are the differences between ovals, rectangles, triangles and diamonds?

Comment: The symbols are from ER diagramming. I've added the legend.

Comment: You could also try asking this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: +1 for pre-work before asking ( and doing Chen diagrams on Omnigraffle ;-) ). You might wanna try with [crow foot notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model#Crow.27s_Foot_Notation) or UML. People might be more familiar with those than with Chen/E-R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing just jumped out at me. Although activities have addresses, people don't. That seems really, really odd.

I'd say,  "Activities happen at one or more locations". So activities don't have addresses at all, but their location or locations do. Also, depending on how you define "activity", a single activity might take place at different locations at different times. So, for example, if "group protest of war in Iraq" were an activity, it might take place at the courthouse today, and at the library tomorrow. Of course, for you those two events might be two different activities.

What address would you use for online activities?

Comment: People don't have addresses because we're not interested in collecting them. It's a student club, all we really care about is the name for the name tags, and the studentid for federation of students paperwork.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I did think about this, but realistically we'll only have events at one location. I don't think events running in parallel will ever be possible -- it's just not feasible given our resources. Because of this reason, I avoided over designing. We also don't conduct online activities -- we do dance workshops, etc.